# Laravel response resource png

Tags: php, laravel, minecraft

I'm currently trying to reproduce a PNG in Laravel as a response which is only presented to me as a data type resource.
And although I read the textures of a Minecraft skin and want to render the head of the player, I can't get the content to be recognized as PNG. If I want to display the image as a response via Laravel he always complains about the type and if I let it be displayed with imagepng it is not available as a real mimetype in the browser.
Code below

Head Method:

```
public static function head($rawSkin, $scale = 1, $vertRot = 0, $horRot = 0, $helmet = true){
        imagesavealpha($rawSkin, true);
        //we don't need create new **transparent** image because we use the full image size
        $canvas = imagecreatetruecolor(self::HEAD_SIZE * $scale, self::HEAD_SIZE * $scale);
        imagecopyresampled($canvas, $rawSkin, 0 * $scale, 0 * $scale, 8, 8
            , self::HEAD_SIZE * $scale, self::HEAD_SIZE * $scale, 8, 8);
        return $canvas;
    }
```

Skinload Method:

```
 private function getImage($uuid){
        $result = file_get_contents("https://sessionserver.mojang.com/session/minecraft/profile/".$uuid);
        $result = json_decode($result);
        $textures = $result->properties[0]->value;
        $textures = json_decode(base64_decode($textures));
        return imagecreatefrompng($textures->textures->SKIN->url);
    }
```

Response Method:

```
function renderHeadByUUID(Request $request){
        if(isset($request->uuid)){
            header("Content-type: image/png");
            imagepng(MinecraftSkins::head($this->getImage($request->uuid)));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you show your error message please

Comment: with this code there is no errormsg only he does not set the mime type

Comment: But when I execute `return response(MinecraftSkins::head($this->getImage($request->uuid)))->header(header('Content-Type', 'image/png'));` the mistake comes "UnexpectedValueException
The Response content must be a string or object implementing __toString(), "resource" given." And unfortunately I can't find a way to get a Laravel response from the resource.

Comment: Try to encrypt your content before passing it to response. Encrypt your outgoing image content in `base64_encode($img_src)`

Comment: "base64_encode() expects parameter 1 to be string, resource given" self Problem

Comment: i have now found a somewhat unconventional method where you use the php methods header and imagepng and then let php die with 'die()' to display the image correctly. If you know a better method it would be nice to let me know, because I'm not quite satisfied with this variant yet.